# Trimmomatic not acknowleding commands over Linux cluster

Tags: java, linux, cluster-computing, bioinformatics

I am trying to use the program Trimmomatic to removed adapter sequences from an Illumina paired-end read over a computer cluster. While I can get the program to open, it will either not acknowledge the commands I enter or will return an error message. I have tried all kinds of permutations of the input commands without success. Examples of input code and error messages are below

**Code:**

```
java -classpath /*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/trimmomatic-0.32.jar org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE \
-phred33 -trimlog /Results/log.txt \
~/*filepath*/data_R1.fq ~/*filepath*/data_R2.fq \
ILLUMINACLIP:/*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10:3:"true"
```

**Results: (the o/s seems to find and execute the software, but is not feeding in the command; I get the same result if I use the java -jar  option for executing Trimmomatic)**

```
TrimmomaticPE [-threads <threads>] [-phred33|-phred64] [-trimlog <trimLogFile>] [-basein <inputBase> | <inputFile1> <inputFile2>] [-baseout <outputBase> | <outputFile1P> <outputFile1U> <outputFile2P> <outputFile2U>] <trimmer1>...
```

**Code: (If I add in the command PE immediately before all other commands, the program executes and can find the fasta file containing the adapter sequences, but then searches for and cannot fund a file called 'PE')**

```
java -classpath /*filepath*/trimmomatic-0.32.jar org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE \
PE -phred33 -trimlog /Results/log.txt \
~/*filepath*/data_R1.fq ~/*filepath*/data_R2.fq \
ILLUMINACLIP:/*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10:3:"true"
```

**Results: (Programs rus and finds the fasta file of adapter sequences, but then fails to execute. Why is it looking for a PE file?)**

```
TrimmomaticPE: Started with arguments: PE -phred33 -trimlog /Results/log.txt /*filepath*/data_R1.fq /*filepath*/data_R2.fq ILLUMINACLIP:/*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10:3:true
Multiple cores found: Using 12 threads
Using PrefixPair: 'TACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCT' and 'GTGACTGGAGTTCAGACGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCT'
Using Long Clipping Sequence: 'AGATCGGAAGAGCACACGTCTGAACTCCAGTCAC'
Using Long Clipping Sequence: 'TACACTCTTTCCCTACACGACGCTCTTCCGATCT'
Using Long Clipping Sequence: 'GTGACTGGAGTTCAGACGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCT'
Using Long Clipping Sequence: 'AGATCGGAAGAGCGTCGTGTAGGGAAAGAGTGTA'
ILLUMINACLIP: Using 1 prefix pairs, 4 forward/reverse sequences, 0 forward only sequences, 0 reverse only sequences
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: PE (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
        at org.usadellab.trimmomatic.fastq.FastqParser.parse(FastqParser.java:127)
        at org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE.process(TrimmomaticPE.java:251)
        at org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE.run(TrimmomaticPE.java:498)
        at org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE.main(TrimmomaticPE.java:506)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used trimmomatic but it looks like you are passing in the incorrect parameters.

the  [trimmomatic webpage](http://www.usadellab.org/cms/?page=trimmomatic) lists the usage from version 0.27+ as:

`java -jar <path to trimmomatic.jar> PE [-threads <threads] [-phred33 | -phred64] [-trimlog <logFile>] <input 1> <input 2> <paired output 1> <unpaired output 1> <paired output 2> <unpaired output 2> <step 1> ...`

or using the "old way"
`java -classpath <path to trimmomatic jar> org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE [-threads <threads>] [-phred33 | -phred64] [-trimlog <logFile>] <input 1> <input 2> <paired output 1> <unpaired output 1> <paired output 2> <unpaired output 2> <step 1> ...`

Where the only difference is the new way is specifying "PE" as the main class instead of a fully qualified path.

**First, addressing your 2nd problem:**

You look like you are doing both: specifying a fully qualified class name as well as the PE part.  This makes trimmomatic think you have a fastq file named "PE" which doesn't exist.

If you get rid of the "PE" OR the qualfited class name; it will call the correct class.  Which is what you do first in your first problem.

**1st problem**
I don't think you have the correct number of arguments listed in your first invocation so trimmomatic displays the usage to tell you what parameters are required.  It would be nice if it told you what was wrong but it doesn't.

**Solution**
It looks like you are only providing 2 fastq files but trimmmoatic needs **6** file paths.  You are missing the output paired and unpaired files paths for the read 1 and read 2 data which I assume get created by the program when it runs.

I guess your 2nd attempt got further along in the program since it saw enough parameters that you potentially had enough file paths specified (however, it turns out you had optional step parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of dkatzel below and user blakeoft on SeqAnswers (http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=45094), I dropped the PE flag and added individual file names for each output file and the program executed properly.

```
java -classpath /*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/trimmomatic-0.32.jar org.usadellab.trimmomatic.TrimmomaticPE \
-phred33 \
~/refs/lec12/data_R1.fq ~/refs/lec12/data_R2.fq \
lane1_forward_paired.fq lane1_forward_unpaired.fq lane1_reverse_paired.fq lane1_reverse_unpaired.fq \
ILLUMINACLIP:/*filepath*/Trimmomatic-0.32/adapters/TruSeq3-PE-2.fa:2:30:10:3:true
```

**NB:** I also tried using the -baseout  flag rather than a list of four files, and the program would open but not execute any commands

**NB:** The a log file could be generated using the flag -trimlog *filename*, but only if I first made a blank text file with the same name as the intended log file.

Comment: How is that different than my answer above?

Comment: Sorry dkatzel. The answers are essentially the same. In my efforts to be thorough by acknowledging blakeoft I accidentally forgot to credit your answer also. This has been amended.